Issue with NGINX and Nuxt in Docker: _nuxt Files Not Found (404)
I am working on a project that uses Symfony (backend) and Nuxt (frontend) running inside Docker containers. While the Symfony APIs work perfectly, I am encountering an issue where NGINX is not serving the static files from Nuxt, particularly those in the _nuxt/ directory, returning a 404 error.
Here’s the setup:

Backend: Symfony
Frontend: Nuxt 3 (with SSR)
Web Server: NGINX
Database: MariaDB

The APIs from Symfony are being served correctly through NGINX, but Nuxt’s static files (specifically those in _nuxt/) are returning 404 errors. I have verified that the Nuxt files are being built and output correctly in the .output/public/_nuxt/ folder, but NGINX doesn’t seem to serve them properly.
Here is my current configuration:
1. docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    container_name: "mariadb"
    command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod

  php:
    build: ./back/php-fpm
    container_name: "php"
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ../back:/var/www/symfony:cached
      - ../log/symfony:/var/www/symfony/var/log:cached
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod

  nginx:
    build: ./back/nginx
    container_name: "nginx"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ../back:/var/www/symfony:cached
      - ../front/.output:/var/www/html/nuxt/.output
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod

  nuxt:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: infra/front/Dockerfile
    container_name: "nuxt"
    volumes:
      - ../front/.output:/var/www/html/nuxt/.output
    expose:
      - "3000"

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

nginx.conf:
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stderr crit;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

3. config.conf (specific NGINX configuration)
upstream php-upstream {
    server php:9001;  # PHP-FPM listening on this port for Symfony
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    # Proxy for Nuxt.js (frontend application)
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nuxt:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Handle _nuxt/ static files
    location /_nuxt/ {
        alias /var/www/html/nuxt/.output/public/_nuxt/;  # Absolute path to _nuxt files
        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stderr;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Handle Symfony static files
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        root /var/www/symfony/public;  # Root for Symfony static files
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Proxy requests to Symfony API through PHP-FPM
    location /api/ {
        root /var/www/symfony/public;  # Root for Symfony API
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # PHP-FPM handling for Symfony
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        root /var/www/symfony/public;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $https if_not_empty;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }

    # Redirect logs to stdout/stderr for Docker
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stderr;

    # Custom error pages
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
}

nuxt.config.ts:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: true,
  target: 'static',
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
  },
  generate: {
    dir: '.output/public',
  },
})

Behavior Observed:

Symfony API: Works fine, I can call the API via curl on /api/test and receive the correct response.
Nuxt Files (_nuxt/): When requesting the static files such as /BV9kNyU2.js, I get a 404 error.

Debugging Attempts:

Volume Checks: I verified that the volumes between the nuxt and nginx containers are mounted correctly. When inspecting the containers, the Nuxt files are present at /var/www/html/nuxt/.output/public/_nuxt/.
Logs: No significant errors in NGINX or Nuxt logs indicating a routing or file resolution issue.
Docker Networking: The containers are on the same Docker network and can communicate with each other. Symfony’s API works as expected.

Question:
Why is NGINX unable to serve the static files from Nuxt even though they exist in the container? Am I missing something in the configuration?
Thank you for your help!
This should give you a well-structured post for StackOverflow that clearly outlines the problem and the configurations you’re using. You should receive helpful responses to troubleshoot the issue further.
